# Sequence index is not an int, slice, or instance with __index__

Tags: python

This is my code and the error is on the title pls help

```py
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(3163233361)
secret = '3kdovjdkejazzke8ygth3mdovjokelameks83hnhiknovedkejamzksg31chBkdovjdkejaozksn3gcy3edovjdkejamzkc83gch'
secret = str(secret)
for i in range(21):
    index = np.random.randint(100)
    print(secret[index],end='')
```

Comment: Could not reproduce with the code you posted. Please post the complete error in the question.

Comment: someone is watching Michael Reeeeeves, if you have any error please provide the whole message

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: for me code works without problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran your code, it outputted `Benzoy1methylecgonine` which I assume is the intended output?

One suggestion though for your code, you don't need line 4: `secret = str(secret)` because by putting the '' marks round the characters: '3kdov...' you are automatically making the variable `secret` a string.